# Https non www version of URL not indexed

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url

My website's `https://example.org` version of link is not being indexed by google. My canonical address is set to `https://example.org` but when inspecting google search console `Coverage`, it shows that

> Duplicate, Google chose different canonical than user

and it is excluding my non www. It seems like google wants to take my www site.

Everything is set up correctly, there are no problem with robots.txt, sitemap file is given and everything seems to be fine. If I do a URL inspect on my site. I get the results which I have added below. Sitemaps are shown as N/A, tho if I resubmit sitemaps then it shows them, after a day it's N/A again.

Google says that it is

> duplicate, chose different canonical than user'', but you can see that below it says ''google selected canonical - same as user declared.

I am bit lost here what to do, should I just wait for google to do their thing or is there any problem from my side which I may fix ?

[image: URL inspection]

Comment: How is the www handled? Does it redirect to the bear domain? Or does it show the same content?

Comment: www redirects the site to the non www site. 
On google console www seems all good. It shows that it's indexed and available to google, as well as shows my canonical, but still the non www site is shown as duplicate and excluded due to google wanting to choose different canonical.